# How to tell which oracle process a perl script is using

Tags: perl, oracle11g

I have a perl script that gets data from an Oracle 11G database. Up until last week the script ran in about an hour. Starting last week the scripts runs for over 24 hours and I have to kill it. Is there a way to link the perl script to an Oracle process? (I want to strace the Oracle process.)

Comment: I guess, you had exclusive locks, that's why your script worked so much time. Check the enterprise manager next time you run this script.

Comment: Which OS? If you have access to script make it write somewhere its own PID and oracle client details.

Comment: If the perl script is making a dedicated server connection to the database, this is possible.  But I really can't imagine that you want to strace an Oracle process.  Oracle provides a whole host of tools to identify why an Oracle process is performing poorly-- surely you'd want to use the Oracle tools to identify the Oracle performance issue.

Comment: I guess I should say I'm not a DBA, just the perl reports guy. The OS is Red Hat 5.10. The script is directly connecting to the DB: $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:orcl', '<name>', '<password>',  { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0 }) or die "$DBI::errstr\n"; I'm looking to use strace to just verify that something is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of easy it turns out. Do a 'ps -ef' sorted by PID. Look for the perl script. The oracle process is the next one in the list. Now to figure out why Oracle is having an issue with a semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to strace, you could try setting DBI_TRACE=1 in the perl script's environment and then run the script. DBI will generate a bunch of debugging output, logging all of the queries it runs, and then you can watch as ti runs, and see if one particular query hangs, and then concentrate on profiling and tuning that one.

If that gives you no satisfaction, then you can endeavor to strace Oracle.